# Python xlsxwriter - hex2dec multiple cells

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I created a worksheet from csv data and I want to create a new worksheet and convert all the (hex) data into decimal format. My problem is how to go about mirroring every cell into worksheet 1 and putting it all into worksheet2, where the only difference is the =HEX2DEC(..) on the cell.

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook




for csvfile in ['hexData']:
     workbook   = Workbook(csvfile + '.xlsx')
     worksheet  = workbook.add_worksheet('hexSheet')
     worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('decSheet')
     with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f)
          for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                for c, col in enumerate(row):
                     worksheet.write(r, c, col)

     with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f)
          for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                for c, col in enumerate(row):
                     worksheet2.write_formula(r, c, 'HEX2DEC(hexSheet!A2:hexSheet!F16)')
```

The result is #VALUE! on all cells for the dec worksheet. When I apply that formula manually the same issue occurs so its probably my misunderstanding on the formula itself applying to multiple cells..

Would appreciate some direction on this.

Cheers

Comment: `=` is missing. Try writing quotes, e.g. `'"=HEX2DEC(..."'`. Also, if your system is non-English, beware that the Excel function names are localized (translated).

Comment: Yes I mean't with = included too. It doesnt seem to work still

Comment: You don't have to open the file twice. You can write to both `worksheets` at once.

Answer (score 2):

> When I apply that formula manually the same issue occurs so its probably my misunderstanding on the formula itself applying to multiple cells.

Correct. If the formula isn't valid in Excel [it isn't going to be valid in a file created by XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#dealing-with-formula-errors).

The problem in this case is that `HEX2DEC()` in Excel only takes a singe value and you are passing it a range. So you need something like this:

```
worksheet2.write_formula(r, c, 'HEX2DEC(hexSheet!A2')
```

Here is a complete working example based on yours.

```
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

for csvfile in ['hexData.csv']:
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile + '.xlsx',  {'strings_to_numbers': True})

    worksheet_hex = workbook.add_worksheet('hexSheet')
    worksheet_dec = workbook.add_worksheet('decSheet')

    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet_hex.write(r, c, col)
                worksheet_dec.write_formula(r, c, 'HEX2DEC(hexSheet!%s)' %
                                                  xl_rowcol_to_cell(r, c))

    workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Note:

- The use of `strings_to_numbers` in the [workbook constructor](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#constructor) in case you need that.
- The two loops are consolidated into one.
- The XlsxWriter [`xl_rowcol_to_cell()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html#cell-utility-functions) function is used to create the cell name.

Also note that you may be better off doing the hex2dec conversion in Python rather than using an Excel formula.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried your way and used worksheet_dec.write_formula(r, c, 'HEX2DEC(hexSheet!%s)' % xl_rowcol_to_cell(r, c)) but the resulting sheet gives everything #REF!.

Comment: I would just convert everything in Python but I can't seem to be able to do so due to the way I designed my code. I am creating a CSV file, which I cannot seem to convert to anything other than string when writing to a file.. I then read that file and create the xlsx from there... If I tried to do any int(val, 16) conversion it screws up..

Comment: @arsenal88 I added an output image to show that the code works. A `#REF!` error in Excel is generally caused by an invalid cell reference. Try fix the error in Excel and apply the same fix to your program.